# Matrix Elements Under BCS basis

Tags: superconductivity, wick-theorem, mean-field-theory

I am learning BCS theory but I am stuck at a very beginning step in my deduction. The BCS wave function is
$$
|\rm BCS\rangle=\prod_{k>0}(u_k+v_ka_k^\dagger a_{\bar{k}}^\dagger)|\rm vac\rangle
$$

And the expectation value of an one-body operator should be
$$
\langle \rm BCS|\sum_{k_1k_2}t_{k_1k_2}a_{k_1}^\dagger a_{k_2}|\rm BCS\rangle
$$

Then I encountered an expression like this
$$
\langle[\prod_{k>0}(u_k+v_ka_ka_{\bar{k}})]\sum_{k_1k_2}t_{k_1k_2}a_{k_1}^\dagger a_{k_2}[\prod_{k'>0}(u_{k'}+v_{k'}a_{k'}^\dagger a_{\bar{k'}}^\dagger)]\rangle
$$
This expectation value should be calculated by Wick's theorem, but I don't know how to find all fully contracted terms. Thanks for teaching me.